# intellij's scala plugin is not recognizing symbols in build.sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I imported an existing working sbt project.   Intellij is highlighting many things in the sbt file as errors:

`lazy val core = project.in(file("core"))`

"Cannot resolve symbol project"

"Cannot resolve symbol file"

`scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`

"Cannot resolve symbol scalaVersion"

I have the latest version of intellij and the latest version of the scala plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with this problem right after I saw your question. I have tried everything Junaid said but it did not work. Afterwards, I have re-imported the project by selecting `build.sbt` file and everything worked well.

Whenever IntelliJ could not find Scala SDK or show errors on `build.sbt` file, just try to **re-import project by selecting `build.sbt`.** It should work.

I hope it helps!

Comment: despite saying "project already registered", this worked!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Click File -> Synchronize, and IntelliJ should see that everything is okay again.

If that doesn't work, IntelliJ's caches might be corrupt (this used to happen a lot more often than it does now); in that case, regenerate them by

Clicking File -> Invalidate Caches and restarting the IDE